# emberjs arraycontroller

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I'm using the latest 4th pre release of ember. In my application I have some sections that are not connected to Router, but I would like to keep all application in one style and use `ArrayController` and `Em.CollectionView` for them.

I tried to make something like this:

```
var controller = Em.ArrayController.create({content: Em.A()});
Em.CollectionView.create({
    controller: controller 
});
controller.pushObject(Em.Object.create({
    title: 'test'
}))
```

and then I got an error that "controller" does not have a container property.

**Is it possible to use `ArrayController` without `Em.Router`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I was not able to reproduce the error you specified, but did have to make a few changes to get things working.

```
var controller = Em.ArrayController.create({content: Em.A()});
controller.pushObject(Em.Object.create({title: 'dr plimpton'}));
controller.pushObject(Em.Object.create({title: 'raj'}));
controller.pushObject(Em.Object.create({title: 'howard'}));
controller.pushObject(Em.Object.create({title: 'leonard'}));

var myView = Ember.CollectionView.create({
  tagName: 'ul',
  content: controller,
  itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("{{view.content.title}}")
  })
});

myView.appendTo('body');
```

Working example (based on ember-1.0.0-pre.4) here: http://jsbin.com/eticuw/1/edit